# Setting badge on a tabbar item of chosen type (without knowing its index)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a tabBar in my app. I want to display a badge with a number of unread messages when notification comes. So far my code is below.
The problem is that the messages tab isn't always the first item in the list (the order varies for different app settings, but it's always there). How do I set the badge on it if I don't know which index it has?

```swift
    if let item = self.tabBar.items?.first {
    var count = messages.count
        if item.badgeValue != nil {
            count += Int(item.badgeValue!) ?? 0
        }
        item.badgeValue = "\(count)"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your tabbar is managed by a `UITabBarController`, you can determine the index by checking the type of the view controllers in your tab bar controller.

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController {
    // ... your messages vc
}

if let index = tabbarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(where: { $0 is MessagesViewController }) {
    tabbarController.tabBar.items?[index].badgeValue = "..."
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting first item in first line - so it's working as expected. 
You need to organize your `UITabBar` this way, that you can always identify on which index messages are presented.

One idea would be to keep a reference to it when you configure your `UITabBar` - this way that you can always find under which index messages are shown.
Best way would be to keep corresponding array of views you keep behind your `UITabBar`, and then find the one you need.

If you are using `UITabBarController` you will get it for free - all `UIViewController` are accessible directly via property named `viewControllers`.

If you have custom `ViewController` and just `UITabBar` - you just need to build similar logic that will allow you to keep track on which index certain view controller is shown.

Comment: Nope. I need a solution which will always set it on messages tab, no matter where it is. This has to be that way because it's custom for any user. I need a solution which will give me the index of the particular object in tabbar menu.

Comment: @Sileo1024 yes you need to know index - you just need to keep it somewhere accessible in your custom logic that prepares / updates UITabBar.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this answer. Yes, you're right.